# How to add eventListener in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ejs

I am a newbie in frontend issues. 
When the user changes this html input field, I would like to send the value of the data that he has changed.

Currently the user has only the data that was pre-send to this form and whatever I change it to do, and click on save button. It just doesn't send correct data from a form. It sends predefined value.

```
<script>
    document.getElementById("<%- fieldName%>").addEventListener("onchange", myFunction());
    function myFunction(){
        document.getElementById('<%- fieldName%>').innerHTML = "Hello World!";
    }

</script>
<div class="AknFieldContainer">
<div class="AknFieldContainer-inputContainer">
    <input id="<%- fieldName%>"
    class="AknTextField <%- className %>"
    type="textarea"
    value="<%- value %>"
    >
</div>
```

This code obviously doesn't work. So to whatever user changes the value, I would like to send it.
I guess there are dozen of answers on this, but I just don't know where to find it. Could someone reference me to the solution or build up a solution on the comments below ? I could even use Jquery if needed. If not needed I would prefer to do it in plain Javascript.

EDIT:

So the right question here is how can I make the value of an input field dynamic and dependable from the input ?

Comment: myFunction() and you are referencing the element before it exists...

Comment: `"onchange"` is not a standard event name ... it is `"change"`. Don't confuse it with the inline attribute `onchange`

Comment: Just a tip: input element can't have type "textarea", only "text" (https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html-markup-20120320/input.html).

Comment: Oh, thanks Aleksandar

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass a function as a callback to `addEventListener`. Now you pass a RESULT of function execution.

Make changes to your code as follows:

```
document.getElementById("<%- fieldName%>").addEventListener("change", myFunction);
```

Comment: The event name is `"change"` ... onchange is an attribute name

Comment: Ah, so.. Thanks for the help MysterX and charlietfl. We have moved, but this is not quite what I would like to do. Sorry for my bad english, but I would like to add it to the input tag to the value field ? This means that I have to change this line -  document.getElementById('<%- fieldName%>').innerHTML = "Hello World!"; But I don't know how.

Answer (score 1):

The script should be:

```
<script>
    function myFunction(){
        document.getElementById('<%- fieldName%>').innerHTML = "Hello World!";
    }

    document.getElementById("<%- fieldName%>").addEventListener("change", myFunction);

</script>
```

Comment: No problem, let me know if have any issues.

Comment: Well, I probably didn't explain well enough my problem. But I would like if when a user writes/updates the input field, to be updated. Now it just adds "Hello world!", which is not good enough. Do you understand my problem.

Comment: Can you post your example, you can make use of `keyup` event in that case.